# Failed to start raised network interfaces but restarting after login works

Tags: linux, debian, networking, boot, bonding

I was trying to create a [bridge](/questions/tagged/bridge) connection in order to set up a VM. Before making the bridge connection I made a copy of my `/etc/network`. I notice that something was not working so I restored my previous `/etc/network` in an attempt to correct the problem. But, unfortunately, it didn't work.

When the system starts it fails to raise the network interface. If, afterwards, I login and restart manually it works fine.

The system is a [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) server, to verify this I have to move where the server is, plug a monitor and a keyboard... so I am only able to show an image.

I have also tried adding to crontab a script to restart networking but doesn't work.

The server is running Debian 9 and is a [bonding](/questions/tagged/bonding) network interface .

Any ideas?

[image: The problem]

Comment: Exactly what did you do for "making the bridge connection"? How did you make the backup or `/etc/network` and how did you restore it? The actual reason of the failure is not in the last ten lines of log `systemctl status` shows by default; review/share the output of `journalctl -b -u networking.service` (run as root, possibly even after fixing it manually) for clues.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Finally I saw that ther were some remaining configs in the network folder that when the system restarted tried to turn on some interfaces that later didn't exist. So I deleted everything except my real interfaces and the bonding and the the problem dissapeared.